# WordPress | How to get custom field taxonomy term value

Tags: php, wordpress

I use 2 plugins:

1. Types - to create taxonomy term
2. Advanced Custom Fields - to create custom fields

I have custom field called "age" on taxonomy term called "artist"

Screenshot: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/172306/087480247421ba210f77ffabf7aa046f

For example I have "artist" term called "Angelina Jolie", and his age value is "40"

I want to to get "age" value on **single post** who use the specific artist term, in my example I want to get 40 ("age" value) on every single post who use the "Angelina Jolie" term.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: $value = get_field( "40" );

??

It's not working.

Comment: Did you try the solution I proposed in the comments in the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by AlliterativeAlice, use `get_field()` but pass in the field name, in your case:

```
$value = get_field("age");
```

The content of the `$value` variable should now be 40.

Comment: You mean like this: <?php $value = get_field("age"); echo $value; ?> - Its not working.

Comment: In what template file are you running this code? The default of `get_field()` is to use the current post id, but if there is no current post there won't be one and in that case you will have to pass the post id parameter as well. To clarify: The default behavior of the method will only work in a single post template.

Comment: I think you dont get the situation... for example, I have post called "hello world", on this post I checked "artist" taxonomy term called "Angelina Jolie", and I add custom field on "Angelina Jolie" called "age" with value 40. I want to get "40" on "hello world" post.

Comment: Actually, I think I do get it. Could you answer some of the questions I added in my previous comment? In your code, where have you placed the call to `get_field()`? In what file?

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. The file should be called `single-post.php`, **not** `post-single.php`. Since your template name is not recognized, some default template is used instead, `index.php` or such. This is a quite helpful chart to see which template is used for a particular request: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg Just follow it from left to right.

Comment: By the way, I tested this myself by setting up a local WordPress blog with your exact settings (plugins, etc.)